# Jump #name gives me 404 error on nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

When i click on a button using #jumpto it gives me a 404 error. I think it has something to do with the nginx config file because i am working on it.

How can I use #jump without giving me 404 error?

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name  doutor.pt;
return       301 http://www.doutor.pt$request_uri;
}

server {
    server_name doutor.pt www.doutor.pt;

    access_log   /var/log/nginx/doutor.pt.access.log;
    error_log    /var/log/nginx/doutor.pt.error.log;

    root /var/www/doutor.pt/htdocs;
    index index.php index.html;



location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;


} 
location ~ \.php$ {
include fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
location @rewrite {
rewrite ^/sitemap-doctors-([0-9]+).xml$ /index.php?page_name=sitemap&category=doctors&page=$1 las$
rewrite ^/sitemap-doctors.xml$ /index.php?page_name=sitemap&category=doctors&page=0 last;
rewrite ^/sitemap.xml$ /index.php?page_name=sitemap last;
rewrite ^/category/([0-9]+)-([^/]+)$ /index.php?page_name=doctors&category=$1 last;
rewrite ^/medico/([^/]+)$ /index.php?page_name=medico&doctor_url=$1 last;
rewrite ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /index.php?page_name=$2&page_category=$2 last;

rewrite ^/([^/]+)$ /index.php?page_name=$1 last;

# some default action???
return 404;
 }
```

Comment: `#` symbols never reach the server and so are not processed by NGINX. The `#` symbol is a convenient way to manipulate your page and requests using JavaScript.  TLDR; Let the Javascript handle `#jump` and let NGINX do the rest

Comment: Yes, but it gives me a server error when i use #...What can i do?

Comment: Make sure the request URI leaving your page on it's way to the server doesn't have the `#` in it. Rather send back the URI with a query string like `http://www.example.com/test?jump=true` or something of the sort. Then let your app process the query string appropriately.

Comment: Ok but can I just do something that do not require change the whole code? Like stopping the server from looking at that #jump in the url?

Comment: The server doesn't look at #jump because #jump doesn't reach the server. What's #jump doing on the client-side?

Comment: #jump is just to scroll down a little bit.